# Parse Access List (ACL) in JavaScript

Tags: android, parse-platform

I try to write to the `ParseACL`:

```
    ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    ParseACL acl = new ParseACL();
    acl.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    acl.setWriteAccess(ParseUser.getCurrentUser(), true);
    user.put("room",subscribedChannels.get(0).toString());
    user.saveInBackground();
```

I have already enable the `ParseACL`, what is the issue?
This is the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot setWriteAccess for a user with null id
```

Comment: We should ask you: what is the issue? :-) you didn't say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only assume you are using JS?

From this I can see that the ACL isnt being set on the user. You are missing a line:

```
user.setACL(acl);
```

Comment: Well, has the currentUser got an objectId set in Parse? It looks like you might have a User session saved on the device that is no longer valid. Check the currentUser on the device against the User table in Parse.

Comment: so now to make sure it always saved in session?